# Reference value from one field to another in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Having really advanced form that I should handle in angular 2+. The main problem is that I should duplicate values from one FormArray fields to another FormArray that has completely different structure

Lets say that first FormArray is Aliases and the second is Accounts

1. When alias is added a new account should be created automatically with account name just the same as the alias name. The reference account name field will be read only and the remove account button will be disabled as well, so changing account name from referenced item will not be possible

   ```
   //Aliases:
   [{name: 'Alias 1', address: 'Alias address 1'}]

   //Accounts:
   [{name: 'Alias 1', share: 0}]
   ```
2. When alias name is edited it should be edited at the reference account item as well.

   ```
   //Aliases:
   [{name: 'Alias 11', address: 'Alias address 1'}]

   //Accounts:
   [{name: 'Alias 11', share: 0}]
   ```
3. Account items can be created on their own (without any reference to as alias item)

   ```
   //Aliases:
   [{name: 'Alias 11', address: 'Alias address 1'}]

   //Accounts:
   [{name: 'Before', share: 0}, {name: 'Alias 11', share: 0}, {name: 'After', share: 0}]
   ```
4. When alias is removed

   ```
   //Aliases:
   []

   //Accounts:
   [{name: 'Before', share: 0}, {name: 'After', share: 0}]
   ```
5. Both aliases and accountant modules will be exported to their dedicated components
6. Template driven approach is not a option because the form values changes event is triggered immediately after the form is created no matter on what lifecycle hook is hooked on.

Code sample here...
https://plnkr.co/edit/PhEKXX?p=preview

Here is sample code that I'm storing the FormGroup value as a reference at every account group like so

```
onAddAlias() {
    let group = this.fb.group({
        name: this.fb.control(''),
        address: this.fb.control('')
    });

    (<FormArray> this.form.get('aliases')).push(group);

    (<FormArray> this.form.get('accounts')).push(
        this.fb.group({
            name: this.fb.control(group.get('name').value),
            share: this.fb.control(0),
            refGroup: this.fb.control(group.value)
        })
    );
}
```

but the values are not references to the actual alias values. They are just passed in their current state.

Any ideas how to achieve such a behavior are welcome.

Comment: Why not make it simple Object[{name: 'Peter', alias[{alias info here}], account[{acount info here}]},{name:'Pan'}]

Comment: Because in that case I should use template driven forms and the form value changes is triggered just after the form is displayed (see 6.) which is a big problem for me because of the auto-save feature that should be implemented

Comment: I don't see the problem here?
You have alias1 of peter change it to alias2.
Your template will automatic update the value.
https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8mMai-_HVAhWNEVAKHQtoC4YQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.angulartypescript.com%2Fangular-2-data-binding%2F&psig=AFQjCNHu0qywkhUB3lOYZeK_bvjhdyujzQ&ust=1503735982458895

Comment: Also take a look at ngmodel and ngmodelchange